# Vuetify not picking up styl changes

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

Trying to update style so that buttons are rendered with capitalised case instead of all uppercase.

vue --version is 3.5.5

Added src/stylus/main.styl

```
$button-text-transform = 'capitalize'
@require '~vuetify/src/stylus/app'
```

main.js includes:

```
import "./stylus/main.styl"
```

Problem is that the text in buttons is still uppercase:

Chrome inspect shows style:

```
.v-btn {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Is there anything else I need to do for the app to pickup the styl?

EDIT:
Changed main.styl to:

```
@import '~vuetify/src/stylus/app'
$button-text-transform = 'capitalize'
@import '~vuetify/src/stylus/main'
```

Still all uppercase

Comment: I use `@import` rather that `@require`. Also you might need `@import '~vuetify/src/stylus/app.styl` first, then `$button-text-transform = 'capitalize'`, then `@import '~vuetify/src/stylus/main'` I think because it builds everything to main.

Comment: Thanks for your response @Andrew1325 but still all uppercase - see edit above

Comment: Have you setup stylus loader and webpack like it says [here](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/framework/theme#setup-stylus-loader-with-webpack)? Also, failing all else you can add `class="text-capitalize"` to each v-btn and that will work, but may be a bit tedious.

Comment: @Andrew1325 it says you don't need to do that when using vue-cli 3. My project doesn't seem to have a webpack config file. I think it gets managed by vue-cli

Comment: Yeah you're probably right. I use nuxt and have had to do it but I don't use vue-cli to create a project so that could make a difference. I can't think of anything else for you to try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end after investigating webpack and vue-cli all I was able to do was add to App.vue:

```
<style>
.v-btn {
  text-transform: none;
}
</style>
```